# XNA application crashed after hibernate

Tags: xna, power-management

I create simple XNA fullscreen application. If it is active and the system goes into sleep mode or hibernate mode after resume the application is crashed. How can I solve this problem?

UPD:
I added handler for system message

```
public Game()
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;
    this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
    this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
    this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Bgr565;
    this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
}
void OnPowerChange(Object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Mode)
    {
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
            graphics.ToggleFullScreen();
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            break;
    }
}
```

If application is in window mode, then OnPowerChange() work fine and change resolusion from 1920x1080 to 800x600. But if application is fullscreen mode, then this method not called. Also, I get runtime error here

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Game game = new Game())
    {
        game.Run();
    }
}
```

Error is: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'WindowsGameForm'.

Comment: You have to detect when the system is going into sleep (there should be an event) and deactivate your game, then re-activating when the game has focus, for example.

Comment: I try this solution, but application was crashed before calling handler. If application is window mode, handler work fine.

Comment: I've read a similar problem in another question with getting the handler in fullscreen